# Can I reconfigure the panel layout in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, layout

ideally, I'd prefer to have the debug/console area run the full width below all other panels. In practice, I don't need a full-height search or file browser or error message display; what I need is about the same amount as the editing window takes up.

I think that this isn't possible (which seems really weird), but if anyone knows a way, or a hack to do this, I'd appreciate it…